# Email Template Formula Help

Tags: formula, email-template, merge-field

I have a text field which displays **"Thursday, May 18th 5:00 PM"**. In order to get just the time, I use this formula `{!RIGHT([Object].Field__c, 8)}`.  For this example, this formula returns **5:00 PM**.

What I want now is to have another dynamic formula which adds one and a half hours to that time. So if the time is **5:00 PM** then I want this new formula to show **6:30 PM**.  If the time is **5:30 PM** I want to return **7:00 PM**.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is it a Datetime field?

Comment: Nope it's a text field

Comment: Why not make a datetime to store the value and then use formulas to write out the date as text? Then you're just using math to get the new time. It's a lot easier.

Comment: is there a way to convert the text string "Thursday, May 18th 5:00 PM" to a date/time?

Comment: You would start with date/time field. How is the text being populated?

Comment: I wish I could start with a date/time but the requirements is that we want it as a text field.  The text is being populated as "Thursday, May 18th 5:00 PM".  This is a text value.  Right now I can parse the text field to just get 5:00 PM but now I need to add an hour and a half to that time.  That time can vary also, it can be 5:30 PM, 10:00 AM, 6:45 PM, etc...